# Angular 15 + i18next - Property 'languageChanged' in type 'I18NextEvents' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'ITranslationEvents'

Tags: angular, typescript, i18next, angular15

I try to implement i18next library for Angular in version 15.
For implementation I use "angular-i18next": "^15.0.0-0" and "i18next": "^22.4.6" and below files:

.module.ts file:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {I18NextModule} from 'angular-i18next';
import {I18N_PROVIDERS} from '@config/i18next.config';

const imports = [
    I18NextModule.forRoot(),
]

@NgModule({
    imports: [...imports],
    providers: [
        I18N_PROVIDERS,
    ],
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

and finaly config for i18next file:

```
import {APP_INITIALIZER, LOCALE_ID} from "@angular/core";
import {I18NEXT_SERVICE, ITranslationService} from 'angular-i18next';
import {registerLocaleData} from '@angular/common';
import i18nextLanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
import HttpApi from 'i18next-http-backend';
import localePl from '@angular/common/locales/pl';
import {appSettings} from '@core/const/app-settings';

registerLocaleData(localePl, 'pl-PL')

export function appInit(i18next: ITranslationService) {
    return () => i18next
        .use(HttpApi)
        .use(i18nextLanguageDetector)
        .init({
            supportedLngs: appSettings.languages,
            fallbackLng: 'en-US',
            debug: false,
            returnEmptyString: false,
            defaultNS: 'app',
            load: 'currentOnly',
            ns: [
                'translation',
                'validation',
                'error',
            ],
        })
}

export function localeIdFactory(i18next: ITranslationService) {
    return i18next.language
}

export const I18N_PROVIDERS = [
    {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: appInit,
        deps: [I18NEXT_SERVICE],
        multi: true,
    },
    {
        provide: LOCALE_ID,
        deps: [I18NEXT_SERVICE],
        useFactory: localeIdFactory,
    },
]
```

On application start I receive following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCVtQ.png)

Any ideas?

I tried modyfied several properties in i18next.init but same error still occours.

Comment: did you set up this config by yourself ? or is it the default ?

Comment: @PayamB. It's a default config from documentation. I only added .use(HttpApi) and
        .use(i18nextLanguageDetector)